# Python 3: Executing a For loop x number of times by using a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Edit: Fixed the screwed up brackets, sorry. Should have caught this. Let's see if this clarifies what I'm trying to do.

I want to do a basic program that takes the variable "run" and runs the following code that number of times by using a For loop.

```
run = 3
def program(run):
    for i in range(5):
        print("The number is",i)

program(run)
```

What I want is to get is:

```
the number is 0
the number is 1
the number is 2
the number is 3
the number is 4
the number is 0
the number is 1
the number is 2
the number is 3
the number is 4
the number is 0
the number is 1
the number is 2
the number is 3
the number is 4
```

i.e. the "program" loops however many times I set "run" to equal.

Comment: It should be `range(5)`, not `range[5]`

Comment: It's important to understand the error message and not just fixate on the error

Comment: What is the point of passing `run` to `program` if it is not in use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Most of all, we expect you to use available tutorials and examples *before* posting here.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site.  Any tutorial on `for` loops will teach you this.

Comment: @Prune I did spend multiple hours looking through For tutorials before posting this, and did not find an answer to my specific question that I understood. I don't want a tutorial, I just want to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this particular code chunk. I consider posting questions to Stack an absolute last resort, which is why I've never bothered using it before - it's never been necessary, I've always managed to hunt down answers elsewhere.

Comment: In your own words, *how does the code already* cause the `print` to occur 5 times with different values? What if you tried *using the same technique again*?

Answer (score 4):

Let's break the code and the error message down a bit:

```
    for i in range[5]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

"Subscripting" is the way you access a particular element in a container, like a list or a dict.  For example, to get the first (0th) element of a list called `foo`, you'd say `foo[0]`, and to get the value associated with the key `"bar"` in a dictionary called `foo`, you'd say `foo["bar"]`.

Note that when you just use the `[]` symbols by themselves (instead of putting them after some other identifier), they serve a different purpose: they construct a `list`.  The expression `[5]` is a list that contains a single element (the number `5`).  To represent more elements, you comma-separate them, e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

So what the error is telling you is that a `type` object can't be subscripted.  Does that mean that `range` is a `type`?  Yes!  In Python, a `range` is a type of iterable object that represents a range of numbers.  On its own, the word `range` in a Python program refers to the entire class of `range` objects (that is, a `type` of object), not a particular range object.

You construct a `range` the same way you construct most objects, by calling the type as a constructor function, with parameters in parentheses.  For example, to construct a `range` with 5 numbers in it (0 to 4, similar to the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`) you can simply say `range(5)`.

So to print all the numbers from 0 to 4 you can do:

```
    for i in range(5):
        print("The number is", i)
```

In your code, the `run` variable serves no purpose and can be removed completely.
Functions can take any number of parameters, or none at all, and since in this case your function doesn't do anything with the parameter you pass in, it can be simply:

```
def program():
    for i in range(5):
        print("The number is", i)

program()
```

If you wanted to make the length of the range variable, that would make sense as a parameter -- you just need to pass the parameter along to your `range` construction:

```
def program(num):
    for i in range(num):
        print("The number is", i)

runs = 3
for _ in range(runs):
    program(5)
```

Comment: This fixes the error but doesn't really answer my question. I understand the explanation (thank you!) of brackets versus parenthesis, and I should have caught that. That solves the error.

However, I want to write a program that uses a variable for setting the number of times something loops. I'm trying to hammer out example code for something else, and I need it to run with that variable. This doesn't point me towards any way of looping that I can see.

I want "run=3" to mean "program" executes three times, and if I change it to 4, 10, etc. it will run range(5) that many times.

Comment: To give a better example:
```
run = 3
def program(run):
    for i in range(5):
        print("The number is",i)

program(run)
```
returns:
```
the number is 0
the number is 1
the number is 2
the number is 3
the number is 4
```
but it only returns this once, not the number of times I have specified in run. I know how to do this with a While, but I cannot get For to do it and don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Have your function take an `int` parameter, and use that as the `range` parameter instead of hardcoding 5.  I'll add an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use range, but you would use parenthesis to call the function instead of braces. I.e. `range(5)` instead of `range[5]`. Or you could use your `run` variable like `range(run)`

Comment: Yes, this fixes the error but doesn't answer my question regarding loops with a For statement.

Answer (score 0):

In short you are seeing the error because you are using square brackets and not parentheses `range()` is a function. Change it to

```
def program(run):
    for i in range(5):
        print("The number is",i)

program(run)
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
```

and it works fine.

If you want to the program to loop the same number of times as specified in run then you can do this:

```
run = 5
def program(run):
    for i in range(run):
        print("the number is",i)

program(run)
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. The square brackets versus parenthesis is a good catch, should have noticed that. However, changing line 3 to run just means the program runs through whatever run equals once, it doesn't loop.

I'm trying to run range(5) a total of three times.

Comment: OK so what understand is you want loop through range 5 how ever many of times you specify in run. In that case you can do the following:

`run = 3
def program(run):
    for n in range(run):
        for i in range(5):
            print("The number is",i)
program(run)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def program(n):
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        print("The number is",i)

program(5)
```

ouput

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
The number is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Hopefully understood the assignment:

```
run = 3


def program(run):
    nums = [f'The number is: {n}' for r in range(run) for n in range(5)]
    print('\n'.join(nums))

program(run)
```

This uses list comprehension to loop twice which translates to:

```
run = 3


def program(run):
    for r in range(run):
        for n in range(5):
            print(f'The number is: {n}')

program(run)
```

Or:

```
run = 3


def program():
    for n in range(5):
        print(f'The number is: {n}')

for r in range(run):
    program()
```

Output:

```
The number is: 0
The number is: 1
The number is: 2
The number is: 3
The number is: 4
The number is: 0
The number is: 1
The number is: 2
The number is: 3
The number is: 4
The number is: 0
The number is: 1
The number is: 2
The number is: 3
The number is: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Whelp, I finally figured it out - the reason I couldn't seem to find a solution anywhere to "could this be done and how would I go about it" is that in Python at least, a For statement cannot do this kind of loop, only a While can.

So my experiment of trying to do this via a For is a moot point, it's not something that can be coded without using While.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can absolutely do this very easily with `for` loops.  See my updated answer.